# Swift Protocol conform to two specific classes only

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I want to make a protocol which can only be conformed by UIlabels and UIButton, is there a way ?

Example :

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    func setTextValue()
}
```

I want MyProtocol to only be acessed by UILabel and UIButton and no other class

Comment: As matt notes, it's not currently possible (there's no construct for "or" in Swift's type constraints), but I'm very curious what you're trying to achieve with this. It feels like you would almost certainly be better served with overloads or a full type (most likely a struct or final class). If you could do this, what code would you write that uses it?

Comment: I want to set a value in both these classes and based on that value some of the common properties will be set eg- title, text color etc.

Comment: @EkjotKaur So you’ve asked an x-y question. If that was your goal, you should have asked about that, rather than assuming a solution and asking if that solution was possible.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a very straightforward issue. Just make a protocol that covers the things you want (title, text color, etc), and conform the classes you want to it. Why would you try to *forbid* other types from conforming to your protocol?

Comment: @matt , I do know there are many ways to achieve what i want . but i wanted to know if this can be achieved through protocols ( as mentioned in my question "is there a way") .

Comment: @EkjotKaur UILabel doesn't have a title property

Comment: @Rob Napier,I thought there is no point in  giving access of title and text color to other classes like UIView.

Comment: @Leo Dabus, i meant text :)

Comment: @EkjotKaur I don't know what you mean by "giving access to other classes." Classes don't automatically conform to your protocol just because they happen to have the right properties. Someone has to explicitly request the conformance. What you seem to be asking is whether it's possible to *forbid* the requesting of the conformance. If you just mean "can I have a protocol that *is* only conformed by UILabels and UIButtons," that's completely different than "…can *only be* conformed…"

Comment: Well, UIButton and UILabel do not have properties in common anyway, so the requirements seem silly. (For example, they do not both have a `title` and they do not both have a `text`.) A button has a title label which _is_ a UILabel, but you should not be messing directly with that in most cases.

Comment: If the question is whether _you_ can have only UILabel and UIButton adopt a protocol, of course you can. You just do it. I’ve added that to my answer.

Comment: @matt, Rob Napier was curious in knowing what i wanted to do with that protocol. I just shared an example. I want to do a lot more. It is obvious that setting text to a uibutton means setting text to its title label. Therefore i didn't exaggerate it.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to make a protocol which can only be conformed by UIlabels and UIButton, is there a way ?

Which *can* only be? Not directly, no. You cannot impose upon another programmer a contract such that programmer cannot make some other class adopt your protocol (e.g. forcing the *compiler* to complain if that happens).

But perhaps you mean which *is* only “conformed” (i.e. adopted). In that case, certainly. Nothing prevents *you* from declaring a protocol and then declaring, *yourself*, that UILabel and UIButton *do* adopt it (and not declaring that any other classes adopt it). Just do it.

Comment: Can you share an example?

Comment: An example of what? You still have not shown exactly what you are trying to do. You’ve asked a general “is this possible” question, and I’ve answered exactly that question. If you have a protocol you can just say `extension UIButton : MyProtocol` and and `extension UILabel : MyProtocol` and presto, UIButton and UILabel have adopted it (if your code proceeds to meet the protocol requirements).

Comment: but this protocol can be acessed by UIView and I dont want it. As mentioned in my question i want only two specific classes to acess it

Comment: What do you mean "be accessed by UIView?" If you don't want it, don't conform UIView to the protocol. What you're asking for is not possible in Swift (but we also believe it's not particularly valuable in Swift; we're trying to understand why you think it would be valuable, because you might be right and it might be worth opening an SE about).

Comment: “but this protocol can be acessed by UIView“ no it can’t! You didn’t have UIView adopt it.

Answer (score 0):

An extension may be a better suite for this, especially in swift, depending on what you want you want to do.

```
extension UILabel {
    func greenBackground() {
        self.backgroundColor = .green
    }
}
```

Then you can use it anywhere in your project on any UILabel like this:

```
let label = UILabel()
label.greenBackground()
```